# Avoiding type assertion when using useSelector with Redux, Immutable.js, and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I'm currently working with a combination of Redux, Immutable.js, and TypeScript. I'm having trouble getting proper types from the useSelector hook, and I've resorted to using type assertions. I understand that this is not ideal, and I'm looking for a better way to handle this situation.

Here's an example of my code:

```
  const selectedConInfo = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.conversations.toJS().selectedConInfo,
  ) as Conversation;
  const emailsState = useSelector((state: RootState) =>
    state.emails.get('emails').toJS(),
  );
  const currentEmails = emailsState[selectedConInfo.id] as Email[];
```

I would like to avoid using type assertions (as Conversation and as Email[]) in this code. However, I'm not getting the proper types without them.

Here's the relevant code:

```
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  emails: emailsReducer,
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;

---
const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  emails: Map<string, List<Email>>({}),
  error: null,
};

const emailsReducer = (state = Map(initialState), action: EmailAction) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case EMAILS_FETCH_REQUEST:
      return state.set('loading', true).set('error', null);
    case EMAILS_FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return state
        .set('loading', false)
        .setIn(['emails', action.meta], List(action.payload.data));

...
---


function EmailArea() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const selectedConInfo = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.conversations.toJS().selectedConInfo,
  ) as Conversation;
  const emailsState = useSelector((state: RootState) =>
    state.emails.get('emails').toJS(),
  );
  const currentEmails = emailsState[selectedConInfo.id] as Email[];
```

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to improve the type inference in this situation. Thank you!

Happy coding!

Comment: immutable.js is very old and hasn't seen updates in a long time - it's not too likely that your TS experience with it will become a lot better. Is there any reason you are on this outdated stack and not using something modern (and officially recommended) like Redux Toolkit? That shoud be the default for every new app since 2019.

Comment: I appreciate your insight and recommendation. In this particular case, I was assigned a small project before my company interview, and I was given a base project that already had Immutable.js, TypeScript, and Redux set up. The project guidelines suggested using the existing packages, but allowed for adding new ones if necessary. They also said they recommended using what is currently installed because the installed packages are the ones they are mostly using. So I was trying to finish the project without adding more packages. 
However, I'm grateful for your suggestion and insights. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same struggle. I recommend using Record instead of Map if the type is set. Additionally, you can utilize Immutable.js's List and Map  similar to JavaScript's Array and Map. So, by changing Map to Record and removing toJS, you should obtain the expected type and be able to use it with TypeScript.
The following code snippet demonstrates how I would implement these changes:

```
const initialState: EmailState = {
  loading: false,
  emails: Map<string, Record<EmailInfo>>(),
  error: null,
};

...

function EmailArea() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const selectedConInfo = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.conversations.selectedConInfo,
  );
  const emailsState = useSelector((state: RootState) =>
    state.emails.get('emails'),
  );
```

I hope this revised explanation is smoother and clearer.